# After saving byte array to BLOB, how to convert it to string, when getting data?

Tags: java, string, oracle, blob

In my Oracle table I am using a BLOB field to save the byte array which is originally a JSON string from user input on page.

For example, this is what the client passes to the server:

> "{'AD_ID_NBR':'440111111111177777'}"

On the server side, it will be converted to a byte array and stored into BLOB.

```
byte[] bytes = input.getUserInput();//userInput is byte[]
ps.setBlob(2, new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
```

When returning the user input to the client side, I need to do the reverse.

```
input.setUserInput(rs.getBlob("USER_INPUT").getBytes(1l, (int)rs.getBlob("USER_INPUT").length()));
```

Then on the client side I will get :

> "userInput": "eydBRF9JRF9OQlInOic0NDAxMTExMTExMTExMjIyMjInfQ=="

Obviously it is not what I need. Some conversion should be done here.

My question is how to convert this string into the json string that I had saved before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Blob blob = rs.getBlob("USER_INPUT");
    byte[] bdata = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
    String s = new String(bdata);
```

Comment: a little will be more helpful